# useEffect call different API onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am working with useEffect and want to figure out how to call a different API when an onClick event happens. When my page loads the following is run:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (userData.user) {
            axios   
            .get(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews?email=${userData.user.email}`, userData)
            .then((response) => {  
                console.log(response)
                setReview(response.data)
            });
        }
    }, [userData]);
```

however when a user selects an onClick event on the webpage, I want a different API to be called and for the data from the original request to disappear. Here is the second request I want to send:

```
 axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews?reviewNumber=1`)
        .then(response => { 
            console.log(response)
            setallreviews(response.data)
        })
```

Adding the page code here as requested:

```
return(
        <div>
            {userData.user ? (
        <div>
            <div>
                <FeedbackNav />
            </div>
                <div>
            <div>
                {filterMode ? (
                <div onClick={() => setFilterMode(false)}>
                <h1 className='testing123'>My reviews and feedback</h1>
                    <p className='testing1234'>Reviews are reviews that you have provided on another project</p>
                    <p className='testing1234'>Feedback is feedback that others have provided on your own project</p>
                        <button className='rectangle' onClick={() => setFilterMode(false)}> 
                        <img className='filterImage' src={Filter} />Filter
                        </button>
                    <ul className='filteroptions'>
                        <p className='allreviewsfeedback' onClick={() => {
                            setFilterMode(); 
                            getReviews(); 
                        }}>My reviews</p>
                        <p className='myfeedback' onClick={() => {
                            setFilterMode();
                }}>My feedback</p>
                    </ul>                    
                </div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                    <h1 className='testing123'>My reviews and feedback</h1>
                    <p className='testing1234'>Reviews are reviews that you have provided on another project</p>
                    <p className='testing1234'>Feedback is feedback that others have provided on your own project</p>
                        <button className='rectangle' onClick={() => setFilterMode(true)}> 
                            <img className='filterImage' src={Filter}/>
                            Filter
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>    
            <div className='testing1234'>
                {allreviews.map(allreviews => (
                    <p key={allreviews._id}>{allreviews.review}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className='testing1234'>
                {review.map(review => (
                    <p key={review._id}>{review.review}</p>
                ))}
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    ) : (
        <div>
            <Landing /> 
        </div>
    )}
    </div>
    )
}
```

What is the best way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more context. There are myriad ways to accomplish what you're asking, but one needs context to do so for a specific case.

Comment: @codemonkey added the rest of the page code. Basically I have a filter, when a user hits the page I show all reviews that they have provided; however, when the user filter, then the user should only see feedback that others have provided on their own projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
    setClicked(true);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (clicked) {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews?reviewNumber=1`)
        .then(response => { 
            console.log(response)
            setallreviews(response.data)
            setReview(null);
        });
    } else if (userData.user) {
        axios   
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews?email=${userData.user.email}`, userData)
        .then((response) => {  
            console.log(response)
            setReview(response.data)
        });
    }
}, [userData]);

return (
  <div>
    some text...
    
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click!</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: hmm, this seems to me like it should work but it did not.

Comment: Hm, try to add `clicked` to dependency list in useEffect -> `[clicked, userData]` (as I understood in your code `clicked` === `filterMode`)

Comment: That is correct, clicked === filterMode. I tried adding clicked as a dependency and when I tried to apply the filter I received an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: Good, change `setReview(null);` to `setReview([]);` or change `review.map` to `review?.map` in render method

Answer (score 0):

Listen to search params and call axios.get if search params changed.

```js
const { search } = useLocation(); // import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

useEffect(() => {
  if (!search) return;

  axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews${search}`).then();
}, [search]);
```